# save and retrieve image from database using spring mvc and hibernate Rest services

Tags: java, web-services, hibernate, spring-mvc, jpa

I am developing an application where I need to store Image into db and retrieve.I have done saving part. I stored an Image in byte[] form.when I am retrieving an Image json returning

jThiODUwMjE0MDNlNGFlZTI2MTk1YjBlNDFlYjAwYTI2MTI4OWRlOGU4NGU0OTFlZGU2NzAzMjE2ODA0N2RkMDY5NTkyODg4NzliOWE1ODlhNTNhYTM1OTYxNzZjNTc4YjcwMTJiZmUyNmY1NTJkNzI1MjhkN2FhZjU0ZmU0MWZmMzVjMWJhYzU2NmU3Y2M4NTUzMTBlNWMxODRhMjczYTIwZjhhNDk1MzU0NzhhN2YxNDgxMmYxNzRhNTVhMDI4YzVkYmI3NzgzNWMzNjZkYjFiNDgwN2JhNTUyNDEzMDAzZTJlZmRjYjNkNzFkZTIzZDNiMmNjYTgyN2I4ZTgzM

goes like this 100lines.Here I am seraching by Image Id.

Rest service:

```
@RequestMapping(value="/getphoto/{clsfdimageid}", method=RequestMethod.GET)
    @ResponseBody
    public List<ClassifiedImages> getPhoto(@PathVariable int clsfdimageid)
    {
        System.out.println("entered....................");

        return classifiedService.getImage(clsfdimageid);
    }
```

DaoImpl class:

```
@Override
    public List<ClassifiedImages> getImage(int clsfdimageid) 
    {
        session = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();

        String sql = "SELECT * from tblclsfdimages where clsfdimageid = :clsfdimageid";

        Query query= session.createSQLQuery(sql)
                .addEntity(ClassifiedImages.class)
                .setParameter("clsfdimageid",clsfdimageid);

        List<ClassifiedImages> images = query.list();

        return images;
    }
```

How can I retrieve an Image in json with byte[] format. Thanks in advance for your suggestions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Even if you haven't provided the `ClassifiedImages`, I assume you have a field like:

```
private byte[] image;
```

That string you see it's the Base64 encoded value of your image `byte[]` array. It's perfectly fine and there's nothing wrong with it. REST and JSON demand every contained field to be serialized as String, byte[] arrays included.

So, in the client code you need a Base64 decoder to take the encoded `String` and transform it back to a `byte[]` array and display your image.

Comment: Thanks for your replay and explained very clearly.Now I got the point.You said i need  base64 decoder to convert it into string form.can you please tell me where do i need to write the code in my project.I mean in controller or Dao class?